# How to fix "Cannot find runtime 'nodemon' on PATH. Make sure to have 'nodemon' installed."?

Tags: visual-studio-code, nodemon

I try to debug nodejs app with nodemon on visual studio code so that I can auto restart the debugger each time I save my code. 
However, it just kept poping up this error message when I run my debugger on visual studio code:
"Cannot find runtime 'nodemon' on PATH. Make sure to have 'nodemon' installed"

I have tried to reinstall visual studio code, reinstall nodemon globally and locally.

Here is my `launch.json` file:

````
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "nodemon",
      "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
      "restart": true,
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }
  ]```
````

Answer (score 14):

I solved this issue by installing nodemon as global.

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Comment: Thanks. This fix my issue in my windows system running Node 12+ with VS 1.49.

Updating runtimeExecutable in launch.json does not work for me.
"runtimeExecutable":"d:/nodejson"

Answer (score 4):

The solution I've found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1065325).

First, run the follow command:

```
which node .
```

So then, you will get the node path, something like: "/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node"

Then, you update your launch.json with:

```
{
    ...
    "runtimeExecutable": "/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node"
    ...
}
```

Comment: This solved it for me after I installed NVM. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I often get this error when I restart my computer. The reason is that vscode can't load nodemon's path. The way I fixed it was to close the vscode window that was crashing and reopen it through the terminal with the command "code ./your_folder". Good luck.